# spinner onclick and style?

Tags: android, spinner

i want to display spinner in a title bar,i have done some coding and its working fine but 
  1)spinner is quite black(not visible clearly )
  2)and not able to put on click at sub item

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    View menuView = menu.findItem(R.id.menuSort).getActionView(); 
    selectTitle = (Spinner) menuView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> aAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, NewsTitle);
    selectTitle.setAdapter(aAdpt);  

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Spinner Items Click/Select part, as [Dhara Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2683275/dhara-shah) said use [OnItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html)

And for the Spinner Color part, are you using custom theme ?

Comment: thanks @john  <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item> its working for me thanks for yor info

Answer (score 0):

set onItemSelectedListener for the spinner like

```
spinnerName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {// override the methods});
```

set spinner background to some color or image to make it visible like

```
android:background="@drawable/image"
```

in the xml.